# Items getting double-counted in SQL Server, dependent counting logic not working right

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am counting the number of RFIs (requests for info) from various agencies. Some of these agencies are also part of a task force (committee). Currently this SQL combines the agencies and task forces into one list and counts the RFIs for each. The problem is, if the RFI belongs to a task force (which is also assigned to an agency), I only want it to count for the task force and not for the agency. However, if the agency does not have a task force assigned to the RFI, I want it to still count for the agency. The RFIs are linked to various agencies through a _LinkEnd table, but that logic works just fine. Here is the logic thus far:

```
SELECT t.Submitting_Agency, COUNT(DISTINCT t.Count) AS RFICount 
FROM (
    SELECT RFI_.Submitting_Agency, RFI_.Unique_ID, _LinkEnd.EntityType_ID1, _LinkEnd.Link_ID as Count
        FROM RFI_
            JOIN _LinkEnd ON RFI_.Unique_ID=_LinkEnd.Entity_ID1
        WHERE _LinkEnd.Link_ID LIKE 'CAS%' AND RFI_.Date_Submitted BETWEEN '20110430' AND '20110630'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT RFI_.Task_Force__Initiative AS Submitting_Agency, RFI_.Unique_ID, _LinkEnd.EntityType_ID1, _LinkEnd.Link_ID as Count
        FROM RFI_
        JOIN _LinkEnd ON RFI_.Unique_ID=_LinkEnd.Entity_ID1
        WHERE _LinkEnd.Link_ID LIKE 'CAS%' AND RFI_.Date_Submitted BETWEEN '20110430' AND '20110630' AND RFI_.Task_Force__Initiative IS NOT NULL) t
GROUP BY t.Submitting_Agency
```

How can I get it to only count an RFI one time, even though the two fields are combined? For instance, here are sample records from the RFI_ table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Unique_ID | Submitting_Agency | Task_Force__Initiative | Date_Submitted |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | Social Service    | Flood Relief TF        | 2011-05-08     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2         | Faith-Based Init. | Homeless Shelter Min.  | 2011-06-08     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3         | Psychology Group  |                        | 2011-05-04     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4         | Attorneys at Law  |                        | 2011-05-05     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5         | Social Service    |                        | 2011-05-10     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So assuming only one link existed to one RFI for each of these, the count should be as follows:

```
Social Service        1
Faith-Based Unit.     0
Psychology Group      1
Attorneys at Law      1
Flood Relief TF       1
Homeless Shelter Min. 1
```

Note that if both an agency and a task force are in one record, then the task force gets the count, not the agency. But it is possible for the agency to have a record without a task force, in which case the agency gets the count. How could I get this to work in this fashion so that RFIs are not double-counted? As it stands both the agency and the task force get counted, which I do not want to happen. The task force always gets the count, unless that field is blank, then the agency gets it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than:

```
SELECT t.Submitting_Agency ...
```

Try

```
SELECT
    CASE t.[Task_Force__Initiative]
        WHEN NULL THEN -- Or whatever value constitutes "empty" 
            t.[Submitting_Agency]
        ELSE
            t.[Task_Force__Initiative] 
    END ...
```

and then `GROUP BY` the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

The result will be that your count will aggregate from the proper specified grouping point, rather than from the single agency column.

**EDIT:** From your example it looks like you don't use `NULL` for the empty field but maybe a blank string? In that case you'll want to replace the `NULL` in the `CASE` above with the proper "blank" value. If it is `NULL` then you can `COALESCE` as suggested in the other answer.

**EDIT:** Based on what I *think* your schema is... and your `WHERE` criteria

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(RFI_.[Task_Force__Initiative], RFI_.[Submitting_Agency]),
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    RFI_ 
    JOIN _LinkEnd 
        ON RFI_.[Unique_ID]=_LinkEnd.[Entity_ID1]
WHERE 
    _LinkEnd.[Link_ID] LIKE 'CAS%' 
    AND RFI_.[Date_Submitted] BETWEEN '20110430' AND '20110630'
GROUP BY
    COALESCE(RFI_.[Task_Force__Initiative], RFI_.[Submitting_Agency])
```

Comment: Trying to figure this out, I keep applying it wrong and getting errors. Will read the MSDN article then mark this as the answer if it works.

Comment: @digitaloday just replace your outer select with the `CASE`  is your "empty" field actually `NULL` or is it a blank string? You don't need to `JOIN` any redundant data... post your table schema and I'll rewrite the SQL for you.

Comment: When I replace it, it either can't find the Task Force column for some reason, or if I put the count info back then it has a different error.

Comment: Invalid column name 'Task_Force__Initiative'. Or if I repair that error, then it won't accept the t anymore for the count.

Comment: Can you please paste the entire SQL and insert this where it should go? Because my SQL statement works fine (except it double counts), but when I add this where I think you are telling me to it doesn't execute.

Comment: @digitaloday see my new edit, provided that your `JOIN` to _LinkEnd is one-to-one?

Answer (score 2):

I guess a simple [COLESCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) would do the trick?

```
SELECT COLAESCE(Task_Force__Initiative, Submitting_Agency), COUNT(DISTINCT _LinkEnd.Link_ID) AS RFICount 
  FROM RFI_
  JOIN _LinkEnd ON RFI_.Unique_ID=_LinkEnd.Entity_ID1
 WHERE _LinkEnd.Link_ID LIKE 'CAS%' AND RFI_.Date_Submitted BETWEEN '20110430' AND '20110630'
 GROUP BY COLAESCE(Task_Force__Initiative, Submitting_Agency);
```

Comment: +1 `COALESCE` is the same as my answer, but fewer lines *if* an "empty" field is actually `NULL`, if it's some other value (like blank string) then he'll need to use `CASE`

Comment: This doesn't work, gives this error: "The multi-part identifier "t.Count" could not be bound."

Comment: Because Count is not an actual field in the table, I created it in my previous SQL as a virtual field.

Comment: @digitaloday: Ah, right, my oversight. I corrected the mistake. One last question remains whether you want `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT _LinkEnd.Link_ID)`